# Installing individual plugin with bower

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dependencies, bower

I'm looking at the [d3-plugins](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins) repository and I want to install only the [horizon chart](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/horizon) plugin.

At the moment my `bower.json` file has this entry:

```
"d3-plugins": "*"
```

But this will install the entire repo containing all the other plugins as well.
Is there a way I can specify bower to install only one subdirectory of a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not optimal, but you can point bower directly to the horizon.js URL:

```
"dependencies":{
    "d3-plugins-horizon": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-plugins/master/horizon/horizon.js"
}
```

Comment: IMHO the package name should be "horizon", "d3-horizon", "d3-plugins-horizon" or so instead of "d3-plugins".